# Get the values of Visualforce page

Tags: javascript, dynamic-visualforce

I create a custom visualforce page where user inserts one value (i.e. Indirizzo__c). Now I want to add a button on the vf that create an Event (Salesforce standard Object) and fills one field, inside the Event, with the value inserted by the user.
Now I'm using this code:

```
apex:commandButton value="new Event" onclick="window.location='/00U/e?Indirizzo__c={!$CurrentPage.parameters.Event.Indirizzo__c}&nooverride=1'; return false;"
```

but it doesn't work, because Indirizzo__c is null instead have the value inserted by the user.
How can i do that?

Comment: you want  to create a button on vf page or a custom salesforce button?

Comment: a button on the vf page

Comment: you can write a method to create an event  and insert the value in a field that user entered. You can add the method on action attribute if commandbutton.

Comment: I'm assuming lightning isn't available? Even if it isn't this might help you out some https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_dev_intermediate/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_server

Comment: I explain it badly I'm sorry, but I want that click the commandbutton open the standard Event page creation with a field filled with the value inserted before

Comment: Ohhh so on hitting the button you want go to a link with a VF page that already has that information filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the proper fieldname to get the value populated. To get the field names, use web developer console of chrome. Append it as key value parameter in the URL as shown in the below screenshot.

In VF page the URL will look like something `/00U/e?evt13=" & {!Start_Time__c}  "&evt4=" & {!Date_Proposed__c}.....`

(The above URL is only an example and not tested.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you with the tips from Saroj I solve the problem. Thank you thank you thank you